# How can we merge two column values in one with pipe in between them using quicksight?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

End goal is to bring number value and its % at one place like there are two columns number of units and its percentage and I would like to make to make it one like:
2921 | 42.0%

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom calculated field with a `concat()` operation. The field description could be something like this - `concat({value_column},' | ', {percentage_val_column},'%')`

Let me know if it works.